# NSMutableDictionary setValue:forKeyPath: setting more than one key

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

```
// populate 'project' with contents of key in `gDictRoot`
NSDictionary *project = [gDictRoot valueForKeyPath:@"root.project0"];

// modify 'project' as necessary - actual code omitted for brevity
[project setValue:[someDict valueForKey:@"foo"] forKeyPath:@"parameters.foo"];

// add 'project' to 'gDictRoot' so it isn't lost when the view is dismissed
[gDictRoot setValue:project forKeyPath:@"root.project2"];
```

Third line, where I add `project` to `gDictRoot` – `project0` also gets modified. Don't know why.

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"%p %p", [gDictRoot valueForKeyPath:@"root.project0"], [gDictRoot valueForKeyPath:@"root.project2"]);` give you ?

Comment: `0x6b9cc10 0x6b9cc10` ... I take it I'm initializing `project` improperly?

Comment: You are initializing it as a pointer to the same thing that's at `@"root.project0"` in the root dictionary.  Maybe you wanted a copy?

Comment: Just got `0x6b3eb30 0x6b27d90` so that should be fixed, but `gDictRoot` is still saving `project` to both `root.project0` and `root.project2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior that you see is due to the fact that both `project0` and `project2` point to the same dictionary instance. The change to one of them will always reflect in the other one.

If you do not want this behavior, make a copy of `project0` before making it `project2`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *project = [NSMutableDictionary
    dictionaryWithDictionary:[gDictRoot valueForKeyPath:@"root.project0"]
];
```

Comment: Thought it worked. Not so much.

Comment: @Thromordyn This would copy the first-level objects, but the references to the second, third, and higher-level objects would remain the same. If you need a deeper cloning, take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1950361/335858) and [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1950404/335858).

Comment: I see. Have to loop again. That or read from a plist, since that's what I'll end up doing eventually anyway. Thanks for the help.