# Mutable deep-copy of a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: copy, nsdictionary, iteration, nsmutabledictionary, deep-copy

First of all I found something similar: 
[deep mutable copy of a NSMutableDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950361/deep-mutable-copy-of-a-nsmutabledictionary) 
but it didn't solve my problem.

I have a NSMutableDictionary as a template.

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionaryTemplate = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"obj1, @"key1",@"obj2, @"key2",nil];
```

Now I would like to copy this dictionary, then change some parts and later save it in a NSMutable Array.

```
NSMutableArray *savedIterations = [NSMutableArray new];

//some loop that normally would change the objects added
int i=0;
for (i < 5){

    NSMutableDictionary *copiedDictionary = [mutableDictionaryTemplate copy];
    [copiedDictionary setObject:@"obj3" forKey:@"key3"];
    [savedIterations addObject:copiedDictionary];

    i++;
}
```

My problem is that once I copy the NSMutableDictionary "mutableDictionaryTemplate" it no longer is mutable. But I need to copy it because otherwise I will have the same NSMutableDictionary at every index of my NSMutableArray "savedIterations" (at least I think so). I tried mutable copy as well but there I change the "mutableDictionaryTemplate" when I change "copiedDictionary". I think I have something messed up with what I have to copy and what not and how to copy it correctly.
It would be great if someone could point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *destinationDictionary = (NSMutableDictionary *)CFBridgingRelease(CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFPropertyListRef)(sourceDictionary), kCFPropertyListMutableContainers));
```