# __NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey: Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

The problem is that I am mutating a `NSDictionary`, but even after getting a `mutableCopy`, the app crashes.

Below is **Method** for copy :

```
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)updateQuery:(NSMutableDictionary *)currentQuery toSearchAfterAccountPaginationSequence:(NSString *)accountPaginationSequence {

    //try1
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableQuery = [currentQuery mutableCopy];

    //try2 
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableQuery2=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:currentQuery];

    //crashes on this line
    mutableQuery[@"where"][@"account_pagination_sequence"] = @{ @"lt" : accountPaginationSequence };

    return mutableQuery;
}
```

**Error Log (the app crashes on a limited amount of devices)**

```
[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: `mutableQuery` should be mutable, but `mutableQuery[@"where"]` doesn't have to. You can have info there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950361/deep-mutable-copy-of-a-nsmutabledictionary to create a "deepMutableCopy", (except its prior to ARC)

Comment: Check that  `currentQuery` is kind of NSDictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this is what you trying to achieve

```objective-c
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)updateQuery:(NSMutableDictionary *)currentQuery toSearchAfterAccountPaginationSequence:(NSString *)accountPaginationSequence {

    //try1
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableQuery = currentQuery.mutableCopy;
    NSMutableDictionary *where =  mutableQuery[@"where"].mutableCopy;

    where[@"account_pagination_sequence"] = @{ @"lt" : accountPaginationSequence };
    mutableQuery[@"where"] =  where;

    return mutableQuery;
}
```

Edit:
In Objective-C calling mutableCopy on objects is not recursive.You need to call mutableCopy in nested objects too.