# NSMutableDictionary assignment

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

Facing issue with `NSMutableDictionary`,

I have one main mutable dictionary, which is `dictMain`,

Taken another mutable dictionary, which is `dictSubMain`,

Declaration as below in ViewController.m file,

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictMain;
    NSMutableDictionary *dictSubMain;
}
```

Now I have some values filled in `dictMain` initially from viewDidLoad method.

I have one another method, in which very firstly I am assigning `dictMain` to another mutable dictionary `dictSubMain` then I made some changes in `dictSubMain` but the issue is whatever changes I am making in `dictSubMain` that same changes reflecting on `dictMain` also. I don't want to make any changes in `dictMain`.

Below is my code,

```
-(void)addRowsInTable:(NSInteger)index
{
    dictSubMain = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dictMain];

     NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     NSMutableDictionary *tmpDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [tmpDic setObject:self.btnTTNumDent.currentTitle forKey:kNUMDENT_T];
    [tmpDic setObject:self.btnTTSizeDent.currentTitle forKey:kSIZEDENT_T];
    [tmpArray addObject:tmpDic];
    [[[dictSubMain valueForKey:kDATA] objectAtIndex:index] setObject:tmpArray forKey:kTABLE];
}
```

Can anyone help me out to resolve it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stop confusing yourself and everyone else. Declare properties. And make instance variables start with an underscore. Since properties, instance variables, global variables, parameters, local variables all look the same in your code, you _will_ have hard to find bugs. And don't use valueForKey. Read it's documentation and use it if that's what you want to use, but not for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `dictSubMain[kDATA]` is an array of mutable dictionaries.  You are probably having a problem because `[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dictMain]` creates a shallow copy of `dictMain`, so `dictSubMain` contains the same instance of the array at `kDATA` as `dictMain`.

You need to perform a deep copy instead.  Methods for doing so are easily searched for.  I am sure there are many answers available on SO.

Comment: Well! Let me check. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1950920/3825016 deep copy worked for me. (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSMutableDictionary *dictMain;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSMutableDictionary *dictSubMain;
```

Actually actually whenever you use `NSMutable*` style use `copy` keyword, that's why it exists.

Or change:

```
dictSubMain = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dictMain];
```

to:

```
dictSubMain = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dictMain copyItems:YES];
```

Comment: Those are functionally identical, and your answer will not solve his issue.

Comment: Try to add copy property, actually Whenever you use `NSMutable` style use `copy` keyword.

Comment: @Gati You don't have to use self execute deep copy way that's theory. Check my edit. Long time didn't use Objc, *deep copy* was in api method already.